# django - AttributeError at /signup/ 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: python, django

I implemented 2FA in my Django application however I am getting `AttributeError at /signup/ 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'` error when clicking submit in my SignIn form. It shows me that error occurs in `six.text_type(user.profile.email_confirmed)` line.

I don't have any custom User model. I am using default User model.

Could you please tell me wjere is the issue and how to fix it?

[image]

tokens.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six

class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.profile.email_confirmed)
        )

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.contrib import messages


# Sign Up View
class SignUpView(View):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'user/register.html'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your Account'
            message = render_to_string('user/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)

            messages.success(request, ('Please Confirm your email to complete registration.'))

            return redirect('login')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

class ActivateAccount(View):

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_active = True
            user.profile.email_confirmed = True
            user.save()
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            messages.success(request, ('Your account have been confirmed.'))
            return redirect('homepage')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, ('The confirmation link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.'))
            return redirect('homepage')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField


# Sign Up Form
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter a valid email address')
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    
    def clean_email(self):
        submitted_data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if '@emaildomain.com' not in submitted_data:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must register using a emaildomain address')
        return submitted_data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            'password1', 
            'password2', 
            'captcha'
            ]
```

Comment: Share the full error traceback

Comment: @Sumithran I changed the image and pasted full error trceback

Comment: can you show the model of User table

Comment: @starboy_jb I didn't override User model. I am using default User object from django.contrib.auth.models